# WPF Expander MouseOver Issue

Tags: wpf, onmouseover, expander

I have Expander control which shows list of items when you expand it. If i do mouse hover over on header, it will expand it.

I need following things which needs to be implemented from code behind or in xaml.

1) if user do mouseover on expander header and press enter key then by default first item from the list needs to be selected.

2) if user do mouseover on one of the item of list and press enter key then we have to select perticular item. - I already have this implemented.

My question is I am able to capture enter key event in code behind but how would I know that user has mouse over on expander header or expander item as I have to do two diff things.

Thanks

Dee

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Mouse.DirectlyOver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.directlyover.aspx) to get the element it's over, you can then walk up the tree to see if you are in your relevant scope (i.e. find the expander/header), or you can check the [`IsMouseOver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ismouseover.aspx) of the relevant controls instead, which should also return true if the mouse is over a child element.

Comment: On moue over I am able to get expander control but I dont know how to find out that it's exapnder header area or item ares ?

Comment: @user2203652: Don't use the mouse but key events; name or tag the control in the header, then either walk the tree until you find the tagged control or check `control.IsMouseOver`, `control` being the name.